# VBA Code to extract First and Last Name from email format firstname.lastname@email.com

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a vba code which extracts First Name and Last Name from email format firstname.lastname@email.com

The below formulas work but I would like them as a vba code so I can use it as part of a list of Call Modules that I have set up.

First Name
=LEFT(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1),FIND("@",A2)-1)

Last Name
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)),FIND("@",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)))-1)

The First Name will start from Column B2 and the Last Name from Column C2.

Thanks!

Comment: `firstName = Split("firstname.lastname@email.com",".")(0)` and `lastName = split(split("firstname.lastname@email.com",".")(1),"@")(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub ExtractNames()
      Dim Cell As Range, Names() As String
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      For Each Cell In Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Names = Split(Split(Cell, "@")(0) & ".", ".")
        Cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2) = Names
      Next
      Columns("B:C").AutoFit
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked a treat! Thanks so much.

Comment: When someone answers which resolves your question then accept it as answer. Glad i could help @ExcelvbaNovice

Answer (score 1):

As a User Defined Function

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetName(s As String, i As Integer) As String
    Dim ar As Variant
    ar = Split(Left(s, InStr(1, s, "@") - 1), ".")
    If i > 0 Then i = UBound(ar) ' allow for middle names
    GetName = ar(i)
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim i, ws: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To 10
        ws.Range("B" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=GetName(RC[-1],0)" '  0=firstname
        ws.Range("C" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=GetName(RC[-2],1)"  ' 1=lastname
    Next
End Sub
```